# Media playback error : Could not initialize Xv output

Tags: c++, ubuntu, media-player, wxwidgets

I found a simple media player on github : https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/samples/mediaplayer/mediaplayer.cpp

I copied it in a new project and ran it. It seemed to go well until I tried to open a .mp3 file. I got this error: `"Media Playback error. Could not initialize Xv output".`

I work on Ubuntu in a virtual machine so I thought that maybe I'm missing something. I opened `Rhythmbox` and tried to play the same file and I got the same error. I searched on google and found this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/750418/my-rhythmbox-not-playing-mp3

I installed gstreamer `plugins-ugly` and `plugins-bad`, `ubuntu-restricted-extra`. Also, I installed `libxv-dev` because I thought it may have something to do with all of this. It didn't work. I reinstalled `Rhythmbox` and it works just fine now. I thought I had solved the problem I had with the code (mediaplayer) as well but I didn't. I still get the same error.

How can i make it work? And why do I get this error in the first place?

I forgot to mention. I'm also getting these messages :[image: AssertionMessage]

Comment: did you recompile the software after installing all those missing dependencies?

Comment: @Igor I did . It's the same. However, i didn't include anything in my program (I don't know what i should include). Just installed them on the computer.

Comment: did you recompile wxWIdgets prior to that? Also, out of curiosity - are you using the version of the library from the repository or you compile the wxWidgets yourself. If its the latter - which configure options did you use?

Comment: @Igor I did not recompile wxWidgets prior to that. I installed the library with synaptic therefore i use the version (version 3.0.2) from ubuntu repositories.   I did not compile and did not configure anything about the library. Just installed it and included in my project (using cmake because my IDE uses cmake for that purpose ) .

Comment: @Igor Maybe that's the problem. Should i recompile the library? How do you do that?

Comment: I am not using Ubuntu, so don't know. But presumably wxWidgets is split in their repository. Try to ask on the wx-forum for the name of the wxWidsgets media package for Ubuntu - I'm almost sure you are missing one. Or if you are feeling adventurous - try to compile the library yourself. However it is best to just install whatever you have/provided to you by the distro.

Comment: @Igor You are right, the library is split . However, i already thought about that and installed every package from wxWidgets that contained "media" in their name. Still the same.

Comment: @Igor Do you think reinstalling the library would do something useful?

Comment: you probably need to recompile/reinstall the library with all packages. Also, you can try to install wxwidgets-dev package and run the sample under debugger (gdb - install if not yet installed) and see where the error comes from. It also possible that wxWidgets version you are using does not have GStreamer 1.0 version support and you are using GStreamer 1.0.

Comment: @Igor I tried to reinstall the library. It only got worse. I mean, the error is still there but now my IDE doesn't even "recognize" the majority of  wxWidgets' classes. The amazing part is that the code compiles. There aren't any linker errors either. What is Gstreamer 1.0 version support? I don't seem to find anything on google ( or ubuntu ).

Comment: @Igor  Also, the error comes from the Load() function from wxMediaCtrl. I defined a function in another project with only MediaCtrl -> Load() and I get the same error.

Comment: Gstreamer support in older version of wxWIdgets was made for the version 0.8. It was very recently updated to use version 1.0. So which Gstreamer you are using? It is also quite possible that the update of Gstreamer 1.0 was not complete and you are out of luck. Can you compile and run the media sample that comes from wxWidgets and try to load the file in question? If it fails - can you see where exactly and get a backtrace. Maybe for wxWidgets you need a complete set of plugins to be installed?